Using slots and nested Templates, not working
Im migrating my app from vue 2 to vue 3, whole app is almost migrated but slot part is remaining. I saw breaking changes and it showed that in vue 2 we used named slot as
<h1 slot = "header"></h1> 

but in v3 we should use as
<template #header><h1></h1></template>

But in my app I already have a template inside templated which is needed and adding another template for resolving slot gives error that we cant use nested templates. Demonstration of my code is shown below
<template>
    <!-- eslint-disable vue/valid-v-slot -->
    <HelloVue>
        <template v-if="true">
            <template v-slot:aa>
                sdfgsdgfsd
            </template>
        </template>
    </HelloVue>
    <!-- <PropsVue :title="name" /> -->
    <!-- <PropsVue title="saxena" /> -->
    <!-- <EmitsVue v-if="isVisible" @close="performAction"/> -->
</template>

Note: template below HelloVue is must needed it cant be removed. How can I fix this issue as slot requires to be used in template and vue 3 doesnt allow nested templates to be used

Why not <template #aa v-if="true"></template>?
